# making jquery work in expressjs app

Tags: express

It is a noobish question. 
I am writing an expressjs app. I am not able to get jquery or bootstrap working.

// app.js

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Also tried

```
app.use(__dirname + '/public');
or
app.use(path.join(__dirname + '/public'))
or
app.set(__dirname + '/public');
or
app.set(path.join(__dirname + '/public'))
```

// views/home.html

```
<head>
    <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $(function(){
     alert('hello');
    });
</script>
</body>
```

//public>js>jquery.min.js

It is not working. I am using express 4.

Template works fine other than jquery

I have a need for this to work offline while writing this app, so can not use CDN

DIRECTORY STRUCTURE

```
    app.js
    views
    --layouts
    --partials
    public
    --js
    ----jquery.min.js
```

Using 'hbs' package, handlebars for templating

Thanks

Comment: No sorry, it does not

Comment: Can you include a directory tree of your app? (also, what template engine are you using?)

Comment: Updated question above

Comment: It's not due to the fact that you're view is .html and your using handlebars? (.hbs) is it? I can't see any reason why jQuery isn't loading. Is it throwing a 404 (not found) in the browser?

Comment: It is configured to use .html as extension, so all templates and partials are working fine. And no there is no error thrown. The page will load all other html just fine but jquery does not work.

Comment: I've just done a basic express generated handlebars app and it works with your code (that you've shown). So just to double check, the page loads fine, and jQuery is loading (check network tab in chrome), correct? If so, I'm not sure what is wrong. Posting your full app.js (and other relevant files) would help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you shouldn't be able to reach your view with your current setup. When you say `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`, you are saying that when you hit `http://{hostname}:{portNumber}`, you'll be served content from the the `/public` folder. You shouldn't be able to access any resources on your file system that do not fall within the `/public` folder. So maybe if you set up a folder structure like:

```
app.js
--public
----views
------layouts
------partials
------home.html
----js
------jquery.min.js
```

that I think would work (assuming that your view.html still points to jquery.js in the folder structure correctly).

Comment: I will try that, but AFAIK, hbs templating looks at views, views/layouts and views/partials folders in root directory by default. Correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: Hmm well my point was I think this is a server-side problem, and hbs is all client templating, right? tbh I have experience with express but not hbs. Also, could you update with more detail on the error that you're getting?

Comment: That is the thing. I am not getting any error. Just jquery not working